# Prolem with assigning transactions to the users in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We are using google analytics for tracking the users and revenues. 
Our revenues arrive in batches usually 24-48 hours after the session.

We are using the batch API: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch

with the transaction hit type:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#ecom

We are setting properly (at least we think so) all the parameters:

Example:

```
v=1&tid=TRACKING_ID&cid=CLIENT_ID&t=transaction&tr=EARNINGS_IN_USD&dl=USER_URL
```

We are currently facing following problems:

- almost all our incomes (like 99.8%) are assigned to the returning users (when you look at the tracking data we have < 40% of returning users)
- almost all our incomes are assigned to the users with landing page `not set`

What can be causing that? Why the transactions are not joined with sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is how Google Analytics understands and processes sessions. For example, a group of hits (HTTP requests to `www.google-analytics.com/../collect`) sent by JS code while the visitor interacts with your site within some reasonable time range is considered a session. When a user interacts with your site the next day a new bunch of hits are sent and these hits are processed as a separate session. So when you're sending transaction data in 24-48 hours after the time user last interacted with your site this will create a new session. Since there was a user visit before a transaction data were sent a newly created session is reported as a session of the returning user. In the same manner, since there's no page path / document location parameter in your transaction data this newly created session would have `(not set)` as a landing page.
Check the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en) for more insights.